# How to make an announcement command but you can choose a channel?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I am trying to make an announcement cmd, it wont work because `discord.channel` cant work

```
@bot.tree.command(name="announce", description="say something in a channel from the cloud bot")
@app_commands.checks.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def announce(i : discord.Interaction, channel : discord.channel, message : str):
  em = discord.Embed(
    color=discord.Colour.blue()
  )
  em.title="Announcement"
  em.description=f"@everyone {message}"
  em.set_footer(text=f"announcement by {i.user.mention}")
  await channel.send(embed=em)
```

I tried to use other parents like guild and i / interaction.guild but it didnt work either, please help.

Comment: it is `channel: discord.TextChannel`